# How to get the height of widget as a double value?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working with a `NestedScrollView` and a `SliverAppBar` and need to make adjusments to the `expandedHeight:` value of the `SliverAppBar` based on the height of a widget hosting some text. Currently the `expandedHeight:` is 400.0. However, because of the text widget the 400.0 value may not always render an appropriate design. So I want to make the `expandedHeight:` relative by adding the height of the text widget to the static 400.0 value.

Like this:

`expandedHeight: 400.0 + textWidgetHeight`

I need some help getting only the height value of the widget as a double.

This is the code for the widget:

```html
Container _textWidget(String text) {
  return Container(
    width: 180.0,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
      top: 15.0,
    ),
    child: Text(
      text,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: AppTheme.define().hintColor,
        fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
        fontSize: 10.0,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this, using a combination of `context.size` and `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`.

`SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` is used inside the `build` method of a `Widget` or `State` to schedule a callback function once the rendering of the current frame is completed.

So, first make your `_textWidget` into a new `StatelessWidget`,

```
class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String text;
  var onTextBuild;

  TextWiidget(this.text, this.onTextBuild);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      // This will be called once this frame is built.
      onTextBuild(context.size); // context.size gives the Size that this widget ha occupied.
    });

    return Container(
      width: 180.0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
      child: Text(
        text,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: AppTheme.define().hintColor,
          fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
          fontSize: 10.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, when you are using your `TextWidget`, ensure it's parent is a `StatefulWidget` and create a new state variable,

```
Size textWidgetSize = Size(0, 0);
```

And while using your `TextWidget`, use it like this to get the size and update state.

```
....
TextWidget(text, (size) { 
  setState(() {
     textWidgetSize = size;
  }); 
}),
....
```

Then, in your `SliverAppBar`, you can use your new state variable like this,

```
expandedHeight: 400 + (textWidgetSize != null ? textWidgetSize.height : 0),
```

Comment: Everything worked perfectly! Until I reset the app. It says the following: "LateInitializeationError: field 'textWidgetSize' has not been initialized.

Comment: Maybe we need some form of initState?

Comment: Or get the size before the page is built? I had to set the value as follow: late Size textWidgetSize;

Comment: Never mind I fixed it! Just added the following:      _getTextHeight() {
      double defaultExpandedHeight = 382.0;
      // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
      if (textWidgetSize != null) {
        return defaultExpandedHeight + textWidgetSize!.height;
      } else {
        return defaultExpandedHeight;
      }
    }

Comment: If you have a more efficient way, please let me know!

Comment: Hi, that's one way, you could just do, `expandedHeight: 400 + (textWidgetSize != null ? textWidgetSize.height : 0)`

Comment: Also, initialise like this `Size textWidgetSize = Size(0, 0);`

Comment: So both of our solutions seem to have a little bug, where the screen loads and then quickly resizes itself. Can you think of a way to avoid this?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. If we were probably dealing with parent and child widget with constraint based relationship then may be we couldve gone for cutsom single child layout with a builder. But here we are explicitly setting a direct value to it which is not animatable